# c++ issue with bubble sort in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, bubble-sort

i need some help in c++ bubble sort with linked list. I need to sort a list of int number like 55-10-50-33. I used this code

```
struct lista2{
    int val;
    lista2 *next;
};


void swap(int& x, int& y){
    int tmp ; tmp = x ; x = y ; y = tmp ;
}


ptr_lista2 sort (ptr_lista2 head){
    ptr_lista2 i,j;
    for(i=head; i->next!=NULL;i=i->next){
        for (j=head;j->next!=NULL;j=j->next){
            if(i->val < j->val) swap(i->val, j->val);
        }
    }
    return (head);
}
```

this code return 10-50-55-33. Why? Where is the error? I need 10-33-50-55!!

Thanks a lot to all!

Comment: That's not bubble sort, and I'm not sure your for loops are correctly formulated.

Comment: Try printing `i->val` and `j->val` just before the comparison, and you may quickly see where things go wrong.

Comment: See [this](http://geeksquiz.com/c-program-bubble-sort-linked-list/)

Comment: How can i correct? I need to sort this int linked list. Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that the data is kept in a linked list, yet not the list nodes are exchanged but their members get reassigned.

Comment: I think if I had to describe this sort (once the `for` loops are fixed) it's "inefficient insertion sort", not bubble sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not go to last element because the next pointer of last element is NULL ,

You need to make "j!=nullptr;"

You compare theese guys with themselves (it is not cause of your problem but it does not seem cool :D )

If you want to fix it, make "j=i->next;"

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the right way

for(i=head; i->next!=NULL;i=i->next)
 {
  for (j=i->next;j!=NULL;j=j->next)
  {
   if(i->val > j->val) swap(i->val, j->val);
  }}